# Как вывести данные из БД SQLite Django на html страницу?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, sqlite3, вывод

***Файл models.py***

```
from django.db import models

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Номер")
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Производитель")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.manufacturer

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Производитель"
        verbose_name_plural = "Производители"

class Catalog(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Номер")
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Производитель")
    types = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Тип оборудивания")
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Модель")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name="Описание")
    information = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name="Информация")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.model

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Каталог"
        verbose_name_plural = "Каталоги"
```

***Файл views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, TemplateView
from Tenda.models import Manufacturer, Catalog

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'Tenda/index.html')

class CatalogView(ListView):
    model = Catalog
    template_name = 'catalog.html'

class CatalogDetail(DetailView):
    model = Catalog
    template_name = 'catalog.html'
```

***Файл catalog.html***

```
{% extends "Tenda/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for val in values %}
        <!-- Таблица каталога-->
        <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Номер</th>
              <th scope="col">Производитель</th>
              <th scope="col">Тип</th>
              <th scope="col">Модель</th>
              <th scope="col">Описание</th>
              <th scope="col">Информация</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for catalog in catalogs %}
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>{{ catalog.number }}</td>
              <td>{{ catalog.manufacturer }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        {{val}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Что такое «правильно» и чем показанный вами код не подходит под это «правильное»?

Comment: Без слова «правильно» понятнее не стало: этот код не выводит или в чём проблема?

Comment: Он не выводит данные из БД

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать что не так с ним)

Answer (score -2):

Переменные "catalog.number" и "catalog.manufacturer" из файла "catalog.html" не инициализированы в функции "index" файла "views.py", а точнее эти переменные - поля модели должны являться инициализаторами {{объектов}}, в "catalog.html".

Например так в файле "views.py":

```
from .models import Catalog

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'Tenda/index.html',
                  {
                      'number': Catalog.number,
                      'manufacturer': Catalog.manufacturer,
                  }
                 )
```

А в файле "catalog.html":

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th>
  <td>{{ number }}</td>
  <td>{{ manufacturer }}</td>
</tr>
```